# InflateException when inflating a fragment for a drawer caused by NullPointerException thrown by setContentView() in MainActivity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-studio, android-inflate

Since Android Studio came out I decided to import my project in it from Eclipse. But the app crashes in API 16 but works fine 21. Minimum API is 14 and maximum is 21, I can't try running at something in between because I don't have any device at that level and the emulator won't run it. I wasn't using Gradle on Eclipse but I am in Android Studio.

I'd really love an helping hand cause it's a bit I'm stuck on this problem.

You may find the code shitty and some redundant, I'm sorry in advance but please focus on the main problem.

And thank you!

**Stacktrace**

```
28073-28073/sc.erza.prancer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sc.erza.prancer/sc.erza.prancer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4940)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:425)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2122)
            at sc.erza.prancer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4940)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at sc.erza.prancer.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:104)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:807)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4931)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:425)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2122)
            at sc.erza.prancer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4940)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MainActivity.java**

I cut a part of this Activity away since it wasn't important, it contained three fragments but that code is never reached.

```
package sc.erza.prancer;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
     * navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
     * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private SettingsSpinnerEntryDialog DialogSpinnerSettings;

    protected static AllFilmsDatabase AllFilmsDb;
    protected static SpinnersDatabase SpinnersDb;
    protected static SingleShotDatabase SingleShotDb;
    protected static SQLiteDatabase AllFilmsDBase, SpinnersDBase, SingleShotDBase;

    protected static Cursor AllFilmsCursor, SingleShotCursor;

    protected static Spinner AddFilmCameraSpinner, AddFilmFilmSpinner, AddFilmIsoSpinner, AddFilmTotalTakesSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        try {
            AllFilmsDb = new AllFilmsDatabase(this);
        } 
        catch (SQLException AllFilmsDatabaseExc) {
            AllFilmsDatabaseExc.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            SingleShotDb = new SingleShotDatabase(this);
        }
        catch (SQLException SingleFilmDatabaseExc) {
            SingleFilmDatabaseExc.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            SpinnersDb = new SpinnersDatabase(this);
        } 
        catch (SQLException SpinnerExc) {
            SpinnerExc.printStackTrace();
        }

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

        mTitle = getString(R.string.films_being_used);

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final int googlePlayServiceAvailability = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        switch (googlePlayServiceAvailability) {
            case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
                Log.i("GooglePlayServiceAvailability", "Success!");
                break;
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(googlePlayServiceAvailability, this, 1).show();
                break;
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(googlePlayServiceAvailability, this, 2).show();
                break;
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED:
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(googlePlayServiceAvailability, this, 3).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getFragmentManager();
        switch(position) {
        case 0: 
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, FilmsBeingUsedFragment.newInstance()).commit();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, AddFilmFragment.newInstance()).commit();
            break;
        case 2: 
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, UsedFilmFragment.newInstance()).commit();
            break;
        }

    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.films_being_used);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.add_film);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.used_films);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.settings);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

```
package sc.erza.prancer;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation
 * drawer. See the <a href=
 * "https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction"
 * > design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors
 * implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the
     * user manually expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated
        // awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of
        // actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1, new String[]{
                getString(R.string.films_being_used),
                getString(R.string.add_film),
                getString(R.string.used_films),
                getString(R.string.settings),}));

        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation
     * drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId
     *            The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout
     *            The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open, /*
                                         * "open drawer" description for
                                         * accessibility
                                         */
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close /*
                                         * "close drawer" description for
                                         * accessibility
                                         */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }


                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();  // calls
                                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                    // prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();  // calls
                                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce
        // them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(
                    "Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.
        // See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the
        // action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to
     * show the global app 'context', rather than just what's in the current
     * screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("");
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return getActivity().getActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must
     * implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="sc.erza.prancer.MainActivity" >

    <!--
         As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
    -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <!--
         android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
    -->
    <!--
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container.
    -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="sc.erza.prancer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at sc.erza.prancer.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:104)` -- what is line 104 of `NavigationDrawerFragment.java`?

Comment: This is it. @CommonsWare
`mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),`

Comment: Then `getActionBar()` must be returning `null` for some reason. Are you using a theme that does not have a native action bar?

Comment: @Blackbelt 
Tried, didn't work. Here's the [stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/PMsPSaDg).


This is line NavigationDrawerFragment.java:140

`actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

and this MainActivity.java:97

`mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));`

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm using `android:Theme.Light` for APIs 11, 14 and 16 and `android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar` for 21.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I solved it. I changed the theme for API 16 to `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

getActivity().getApplicationContext(); instead of getActionBar().getThemedContext();